# Content loading during scrolling and seems infinite (what script)

Tags: jquery, thumbnail, load

I've noticed on several websites that when you scroll down it loads content as your scrolling and this seems to go on forever.... What script is used for that loading system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View source. It's Paul Irish's [Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) jQuery plugin, for WordPress.